# Is there an equivalent apple-touch-startup-image for the IPAD?

Tags: iphone, ipad, splash-screen, ipod-touch, iphone-5

For web apps you can set the startup screen with apple-touch-startup-image

What about for iPads?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same issue as well... You need to you use a specific size of 1004*768. i explained it in this blog: http://www.amirnaor.com/?p=71

Answer (score 14):

This will add a Splash Screen to your Web App. Below are the sizes you’ll need for both iPad and iPhone/iPod Touch, and iPhone 5. These include the status bar area as well.

```
<!-- iPhone -->
<link href="http://www.example.com/mobile/images/apple-touch-startup-image-320x460.png"
      media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 480px)
         and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)"
      rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

<!-- iPhone (Retina) -->
<link href="http://www.example.com/mobile/images/apple-touch-startup-image-640x920.png"
      media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 480px)
         and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"
      rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

<!-- iPhone 5 -->
<link href="http://www.example.com/mobile/images/apple-touch-startup-image-640x1096.png"
      media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px)
         and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"
      rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

<!-- iPad -->
<link href="http://www.example.com/mobile/images/apple-touch-startup-image-768x1004.png"
      media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px)
         and (orientation: portrait)
         and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)"
      rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<link href="http://www.example.com/mobile/images/apple-touch-startup-image-748x1024.png"
      media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px)
         and (orientation: landscape)
         and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)"
      rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

<!-- iPad (Retina) -->
<link href="http://www.example.com/mobile/images/apple-touch-startup-image-1536x2008.png"
      media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px)
         and (orientation: portrait)
         and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"
      rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<link href="http://www.example.com/mobile/images/apple-touch-startup-image-1496x2048.png"
      media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px)
         and (orientation: landscape)
         and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"
      rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
```

If creating a Web App for iPad compatibility it’s recommended that both Landscape and Portrait sizes are used.

Comment: The `sizes` attribute isn't understood, you need to use `media` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Portrait image needs to be 768x1004 (note: 1004, not 1024, 20px is for status bar), PNG is the preferred file format.

Landscape image needs to be 1024x748 (note: 748, again 20px for status bar). This image then needs to be **rotated 90 degrees clockwise**, end result is 748x1024.

Link tags in header need to be as follows:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/splash_screen_768x1004.png" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait)" />
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/splash_screen_1024x748.png" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape)" />
```

For the new Retina iPad (if you don't add these, it will use the above with pixel doubling):

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
  href="images/splash_screen_1536x2008.png" 
  media="(device-width: 1536px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" />
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
  href="images/splash_screen_2048x1496.png"
  media="(device-width: 1536px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" />
```

---

Previous answers (including the accepted answer) at time of posting this didn't work with my testing.

Comment: If you're going to downvote me, please explain why so I can fix it.

Comment: Does not device width have to refer to the actual css resolution? Meaning 1024x768

Answer (score 1):

I think Madhup is referring to native apps written in objective c and compiled with xcode.
The OP is trying to make it work for webapps that are added to the homescreen via safari.
Haven't gotten it to work so far :(

Answer (score 1):

I only got the startup image to work by making a PNG image with dimensions of 748x1024. This was tested on an iPad with firmware 3.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

The best explanation of this issue I could find: https://gist.github.com/472519

Note that it only worked for me once I provided a startup image for iPhone and both landscape/portrait for iPad.

Answer (score -1):

From my testing today, it seems the iPad doesn't support the apple-touch-startup-image. It's quite disappointing that the iPhone does support this in OS 3.1, and the iPad doesn't. Also, when using a webapp in a chromeless browser, the viewport isn't set properly.
I do believe both are bugs or omissions in the iPad OS 3.2. Too bad :(
I did ask for it at the apple forums: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/47178

Answer (score -2):

It's the same as the iphone. Put a png named `Default.png` in the resource folder.

Comment: iPad should support all interface orientations. So Default.png only would not work.

Comment: This isn't what the OP is asking about. OP is asking about the Mobile Safari special treatment of `<link>` tags: http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW6