# Adding a startup image to a web app for iPad

Tags: ipad, web-applications, ios8

I've tried adding a startup screen to my application, but it doesn't work (neither from Safari, nor from home screen).

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>

 <!-- Startup images -->

<!-- iOS iPad (retina, portrait) -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 1536px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="images/apple-touch-startup-image-1536x2008.png">    

<!-- iOS iPad (retina, landscape) -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 1536px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="images/apple-touch-startup-image-1496x2048.png">

<!-- iOS iPad (portrait) -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)" href="images/apple-touch-startup-image-768x1004.png">

<!-- iOS iPad (landscape) -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)" href="images/apple-touch-startup-image-748x1024.png">
```

I open it on iPad with retina display. All images are accessible, and load via direct links normally. All landscape images are in portrait format and rotated 90 degrees clockwise. I also tried setting "width" for retina to 2048, with no luck.

Is there anything I missed?

Sources used:
[Mulitple "apple-touch-startup-image" resolutions for iOS web app (esp. for iPad)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687698/mulitple-apple-touch-startup-image-resolutions-for-ios-web-app-esp-for-ipad)
[Is there an equivalent apple-touch-startup-image for the IPAD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634518/is-there-an-equivalent-apple-touch-startup-image-for-the-ipad)
https://miguelmota.com/blog/iphone-and-ipad-web-app-startup-images/